# Can connect to local server remotely, but not locally (ssl)

Tags: networking, ssl, vpn

I have a local server that has a domain pointed to it (through DuckDNS, but I don't think that matters). The local server only accepts https. When I'm connected to an external VPN, I can access my local server through https://www.example.com.

However, locally and on the same network as the server, if I go to my domain, it does not connect. When I ping the domain, I see it hitting (and receiving back from) my network's external IP. If I go directly to the local IP of the sever, it responds fine.

I have the sense that there is something super simple I am missing, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: do you have firewall/iptables? can you do telnet <address> 443?

Comment: Are you behind a NAT router? Lookup NAT hairpinning/loopback https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning

Answer (score 1):

Probably if the name www.example.com **inside** the NAT pointed to the **local** address instead of the **extern** one (please, test it by configuring  **/etc/hosts** or **c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** to make the local address point to **www.example.com**) you could access to your server.

If it was the case (sorry if not, I do not like to make noise), I suggest doing what I have done in my local network to solve a similar problem: install a DNS server inside the LAN (**bind9** in my case) that transforms address in my zones (three domains) to local addresses and acts as a regular DNS for other zones. You should configure your LAN to use the server you have configured as primary DNS.